# Why does function (watcher) keep getting called repeatedly?

Tags: flutter, dart, file-watcher

```
Future<void> _initializePhotoWatcher() async {
  if (await Permission.storage.isGranted) {
    // This gets the primary external storage directory, which may not directly be accessible in Android 10+
    _photoDirectory = Directory("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera");

    if (await _photoDirectory?.exists() ?? false) {
      final watcher = DirectoryWatcher(_photoDirectory!.path);
      watcher.events.listen((event) async {
        if (event.type == ChangeType.ADD) {
          // Cancel any existing timer for the same file
          _debounceMap[event.path]?.cancel();

          // Set a new timer for the file
          _debounceMap[event.path] = Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), () async {
            final file = File(event.path);
            if (await file.exists()) {
              _addStampToPhoto(file);
              // Optionally remove the entry from the map after processing
              _debounceMap.remove(event.path);
            }
          });
        }
      });
    } else {
      print("Camera directory does not exist or is not accessible");
    }
  } else {
    print("Need access to storage.");
  }
}
```

The `_addStampToPhoto(file)` function keeps getting called repeatedly.

Comment: What is the role of the function `_addStampToPhoto`? Does it change the time-stamp of `file` or is it supposed to generate a low resolution image?

Comment: It's a function to process the image to add text(stamp) on it. What was happening was the watcher was looking for any new file additions to the camera folder. The new file would then be stamped. The issue was that newly stamped file was also being considered as a new file thus forming an undesired loop.